# How to solve this error when converted xml file into java file?

Tags: java

```
File xmlSource = new File("/home/ubundu14/Desktop/ramadoss/22-06-2015/xmlreader/XML/xmltocsv.xml");

File stylesheet = new File("/home/ubundu14/Desktop/ramadoss/22-06-2015/xmlreader/XML/xmltocsv.xsl");

Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("file:/home/ubundu14/Desktop/ramadoss/22-06-2015/xmlreader/CSV/ram.csv"));
```

the above lines are reading file in xml and xsl file. it convert to csv file but i got an error for `FileNotFoundException` plz find solution.. below like this

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/ubundu14/Desktop/ramadoss/22-06-2015/xmlreader/file:/home/ubundu14/Desktop/ramadoss/22-06-2015/xmlreader/CSV/ram.csv (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1119)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1028)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1143)
    at xmltocsv.main(xmltocsv.java:35)
```

Comment: `ubundu` this seems odd. Check the path because that is what fails. There isn't a lot we can do about it.

Comment: Check if you have write permission in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `file:` prefix while getting the `ram.csv`.